# Use php://temp wrapper with XMLWriter

Tags: php, wrapper, xmlwriter

Is it possible to use the [php://temp](http://es.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) wrapper to generate an XML file with [XMLWriter](http://es.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php)? I like the features it provides (memory for small files, transparent temporary file for larger output) but I can't get the syntax (if it's even possible):

```
<?php

header('Content-type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8');

$oXMLWriter = new XMLWriter;
$oXMLWriter->openURI('php://temp');
$oXMLWriter->startDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

$oXMLWriter->startElement('test');
$oXMLWriter->text('Hello, World!');
$oXMLWriter->endElement();

$oXMLWriter->endDocument();
// And now? *******
$oXMLWriter->flush();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the purpose of writing to a temp file. Perhaps you want:

```
$oXMLWriter->openURI('php://output');
```

I haven't ever used `XMLWriter` but it doesn't seem to take a handle to a file pointer. I think that's really what you want.

For giggles, here's something that wraps the temp interface:

```
class WeirdStream
{
  static public $files = array();
  private $fp;

  public function stream_open($path)
  {
    $url = parse_url($path);
    self::$files[$url['host']] = fopen('php://temp', 'rw');
    $this->fp = &self::$files[$url['host']];
    return true;
  }

  public function stream_write($data)
  {
    return fwrite($this->fp, $data);
  }
}

stream_wrapper_register('weird', 'WeirdStream');

$oXMLWriter = new XMLWriter;
$oXMLWriter->openURI('weird://a');
// .. do stuff
$oXMLWriter->flush();
```

Now you can get at the file pointer:

```
$fp = WeirdStream::$files['a'];
```

It may be purely in memory, or it may be a temporary file on disk.

You could then loop through the data line by line:

```
fseek($fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
while (!feof($fp)) $line = fgets($fp);
```

But this is all very odd to me.

Comment: Purpose? Store it in a database or add it to a ZIP archive.

Comment: I saw the content-type, so I assumed you were displaying it to the screen. Are you doing both stdout and saving in a DB, etc?

Comment: My code was just a simplified example to work on the technique :)

Comment: To me, the final destination is a crucial piece of information when it comes to deciding which interface to use... XMLWriter doesn't seem to take a pointer to an existing stream, so I don't think you'll get your dual memory/file interface working unless you perhaps register your own custom stream wrapper that does that.

Comment: is it possible to output buffer (`ob_start` etc.) that stream?

Comment: Witty and works as advertised, thank you for taking the time to compose it. I'd say that `php://temp` is not really the attractive choice it could be if XMLWriter would accept `fopen()` file handlers. It's probably more sensible to generate a temp manually with the help of `tempnam()` and forget about using memory for small data sets. The temp wrapper would be too much coding for little benefit.

Answer (score 0):

What do you need to do with the contents of `php://temp` eventually? If you just need a temporary, memory-only storage, then you can use `openMemory()`:

```
$oXMLWriter = new XMLWriter;
$oXMLWriter->openMemory();
$oXMLWriter->startDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

$oXMLWriter->startElement('test');
$oXMLWriter->text('Hello, World!');
$oXMLWriter->endElement();

$oXMLWriter->endDocument();
echo $oXMLWriter->outputMemory ();
```

Comment: Perhaps he doesn't want to store it in memory if it exceeds a certain threshold. It's a bit strange though, because it seems like you'd know before you start how big the file is going to be, at least to some reasonable approximation.

Comment: If he wants to store it in a DB (as suggested above), then I think he must at some point have it in memory. As you said, without knowing the final destination, difficult to provide a good help.

Comment: Yes, it seems like for most things you'd either always want it entirely in memory (to place in a db) or always saved directly to disk (to store) or always sent directly to stdout.